# git pull issue without user name

Tags: git

I hosted a third_party project on server-1/repo1. 
This third_party project is added as ExternalProject in repo2 cmake (The real project). The repo2 is our work. Our build environment is docker based. 
Inside Docker, I am able to clone the repo1 as per configuration of ExternalProject in repo2 cmake. However git pull aka "UpdateCommand" for External Project is failing.  It is failing because I don't have git "user.name" and "user.email" set inside docker.  As per my thinking, I don't need git "user.name" etc config inside docker for the third_party repo.

The git fetch works inside docker.
The git pull is going to add  merge commit and probably that's why it need git "user.name" etc.  To avoid this, I tried

```
git pull --no-commit,
```

but still land into this issue.

Does anybody have insight? The "User Name" for user inside Docker is "User" and There is no email for  docker user "User".

Error on `git pull`:

> Please tell me who you are.
>
> Run
>
> git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
>
> git config --global user.name "Your Name"
>
> to set your account's default identity. Omit --global to set the
>   identity only in this repository.
>
> fatal: empty ident name (for ) not allowed

Comment: You just have to provide any name and email, s.t. git can attach that information to commits and such. You could even just choose "you@example.com" and "Your Name".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to commit, You must provide your `name and email ID` just to attach this information to commits for later usage.

You first run these commands:

```
git config --global user.name "John Doe"
```

Here John Doe is just for an example. You must provide your name. Then run:

```
git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```

Here email ID should be your ID. Then try to use your command.

Here `--global` is optional. However you need to do this only once if you pass the `--global` option.

Comment: Thanks.  I see there is probably no other way out. To solve I added GIT_CONFIG option in ExternalProject_Add  Config in CMAKE and provided a dummy user name/email.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `git` as a way of delivering code, and are okay with **losing changes** (if any) made in the destination repository, then:

```sh
if [ -e app ]; then
    cd app
    git fetch
    git reset --hard origin/master
else
    git clone GIT_URL app
fi
```

`git pull` implies merging/rebasing branches if they diverged. That's why `git` wants you to specify `user.name` and `user.email`.

`git reset --hard` though tells `git` to just switch to the specified commit no matter the cost: discarding working tree changes, overwriting unversioned files if they are in the way.